# Track Every button click in iOS?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a requirement in my app where i need to track every button click on UIView , I want to create a generic method which every button should call before calling their respective actions. Any ideas? I tried hitTestWithEvent method of UIView but the problem with this method is Its getting called twice for one button click.

Answer (score 0):

**You can bind multiple actions with one button.**

You can create subclass of button Say **`TackEventButton`**.

In that class, in `init` method, bind one `touchUpInside` event using `addTarget:` method. Say you have bind `buttonClickTrack:`.

Write code in `buttonClickTrack:` as per your requirement to track button clicks.
`buttonClickTrack:` will always calls, when you click on button, wether you bind other in method in viewController or not.

And wherever you use button create instance of `TackEventButton`, or if you are using storyBoard or XIB set class of that button as `TackEventButton`.

In viewController also bind method for button. So when you use button, your have two methods for your button, one in viewController and one in your custom class of UIButton.